# Setting SonarQube for SSL using IIS and Reverse Proxy throws 502 error

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, url-rewrite-module

I am trying to setup SonarQube with SSL on Windows Server 2019.  I can access the SonarQube server locally on the server using `http://localhost:9000`.

I followed the exact steps as [outlined here](https://jessehouwing.net/sonarqube-configure-ssl-on-windows/) to setup reverse proxy in IIS using URL Rewrite module. I see the Re-Write URL set to `http://http://localhost:9000/{R:1}`

However when I browse https://sonarqube.mydomain.com I get the error below

`502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.`

Is there anything i need to enable in SonarQube to enable Reverse Proxy?

I could not find anything in website's logs `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles`

Answer (score 3):

found it
I don't know why URL Rewrite module was adding URL as `http://http://localhost:9000/{R:1}`

[image]

I manually changed it to `http://localhost:9000/{R:1}` and it worked